# Why does Flyway ignoreMissingMigrations is not taken into account?

Tags: flyway

I have a setup in which migrations from previous scripts were removed.
The flyway configuration specifies that `ignoreMissingMigrations` is `true`.

However, Flyway fails with the following error

> Validate failed: Detected applied migration not resolved locally: *version_x*

where *version_x* is the first version that was removed after baseline.

Why do I get this error although `ignoreMissingMigrations` is `true` ?

Note: Flyway version: 4.2.0

Answer (score 4):

The problem comes from a special setup that Flyway is unable to handle correctly.

We have no newer applied migration, thus Flyway see this migration as a future migration instead of a missing migration. Thus the solution is to set `ignoreFutureMigrations` to `true` in addition to `ignoreMissingMigrations`.